# DOCKER error.. not switching to windows containers .. windows 11 home

Tags: docker

I have upgraded to Windows 11 home edition and installed docker desktop. It is not switching to window containers.

error: windows containers support requires a windows 10 pro or Enterprise build >=  14372.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by upgrading Windows 11 from Home to Professional and re-installing Hyper-V. Do a restart and it should work for you